# Properties of linearity leading to scaling of unit vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

I was watching a KhanAcademy video on linear transformations and at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=422&v=VmfTXVG9S0U) point I got stuck as to how he got to the third and fourth expressions below:

He writes that:

$$L(a\vec{v}) = aL(\vec{v})$$
$$L(\vec{v} + \vec{w}) = L(\vec{v})+L(\vec{w})$$

$$L(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix})= L(x\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}) + L(y\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix})$$

$$xL(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}) + yL(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix})$$

I'm not sure how he got to, given the first two properties of linearity, the third and fourth lines. I'm curious about this and I'm very unfamiliar with more than just the basics of matrix/vector manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Since $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} x \\y\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\end{pmatrix}$,

\begin{align}
L\left(\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\end{pmatrix}\right)=L\left(x\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This really helps. So then he can go from what you have on the right in your second equality to the third line I wrote above because he's implicitly defining $\vec{v} = x\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{w} = y\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and then applying the fact that $L(\vec{v} + \vec{w}) = L(\vec{v})+L(\vec{w})$?

Comment: That's exactly what CY Aries is saying. Then you use the other linearity property ($aL(v)=L(av)$) to pull out the $x$ and the $y$.

Comment: A linear transformation is completely determinded by its values of a basis, but the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ form a basis...